# Create Elastic Beanstalk Environment using RDS Instance Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I used Elastic Beanstalk to upload an application whilst studying, it was part of a group project. However the account got suspended when the billing details were incorrect, this discontinued the application services.

After resolving the account with Amazon the Elastic Beanstalk environment was up and running apart from the RDS instance. I then restored the most recent RDS backup but I can no longer access the MYSQL database with the previous details (Host, DBName and Password) and the application no longer works because the details to connect to the DB are wrong.

I then found out I cannot use a snapshot RDS instance with an existing EB environment, so I am doing the following steps:

- Restore the database to a new RDS instance.
- Make a manual backup of this new RDS instance. Create a new Beanstalk environment using your manual RDS backup.
- Test to make sure everything is working as expected.
- Update URLs or DNS to make sure traffic is routed to your
  new environment

However I do not know how to do step two, can anybody help me on how to create a new EB environment using an RDS Instance Snapshot ?

(So I can access the DB)

Comment: By Manual back up you means snapshot right? you can take manual Snapshot of the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are the steps involved in creation of AWS Beanstalk.

[image]

In this step select the "create RDS" check box.

[image]

When you go to the RDS Configuration step select the snapshot of your database in the drop down and then proceed till the end.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you posted has no field for "selecting an existing snapshot."